# Optimize a SQL query : call a function or do a join?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

What is the fastest in an ORACLE database ?

Call a function inside a select statement to retrive a single value for each row

```
SELECT field1, field2, F_GET_LIBELLE_STATUT( field2 ) FROM table1 WHERE ...
```

with the simple function :

```
create or replace
FUNCTION "F_GET_LIBELLE_STATUT" (v_statut NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
tmpVar VARCHAR2(40);
BEGIN
   select libelle into tmpVar from t_statut_ope where id_statut = v_statut;
   RETURN tmpVar;
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       RETURN '';
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
       RAISE;
END f_get_libelle_statut;
```

Or doing a join in the select statement ?

```
Select a.field1, a.field2, b.libelle
FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN t_statut_ope b ON b.id_statut = a.field2
WHERE ...
```

And is it the same answer if I call a lot of functions (ten or more) in the select and in the clause condition ?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: In this specific scenario, the plain join will outperform the function but that does not mean it allways will. You should always look at the execution plans for your solutions and draw your conclusions from that.

Comment: @Lieven - I agree with the need to treat each case on its merits.  But a join will always be faster than a lookup function of the kind posted here.  It's axiomatic.

Comment: @APC - I tend to agree but I'm a wary about absolute statements like *always* and *never*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anything which can be done in SQL should be done in SQL **(*)**.

A join will always be faster than calling that function because set-based operations are always faster than row by agonizing row. Then you have the overhead of moving between SQL and PL/SQL.  Plus the overhead of handling those NO_DATA_FOUND exceptions, which aren't truly exceptions because gaps are expected and tolerated.  Finally, the optimizer will pick a better plan for the pure SQL option because you have given it all the information it needs.

---

**(*)** I answered this question way back when and I answered it focused on the example given, and I stand by that answer. If we can get the data we need using SQL against tables (via joins,  views, inline views, subqueries) then we should do that. But I want to drill down into the underlying question: why does Oracle support the use of functions in queries? Because sometimes we need to do things we can't do in SQL.

Here are use cases for calling functions that execute SQL (I am thinking primarily of functions invoked through `table()` calls ) instead of using a join (or other SQL constructs such as inline view, WITH clause)  :

1. Query is dynamic. Dynamic SQL requires PL/SQL so a function is yer only man here.
2. Row generation. Using PL/SQL to split the input into multiple strings (such as CSV tokenizing) or perhaps to spawn data, not from a table. Occasionally still valid but regex support and the nifty CONNECT BY LEVEL <= N trick have binned the more common usages.
3. The data is encapsulated behind a PL/SQL API so a function is all we can call.
4. For some bizarre reason we can only get the performance we need by using PL/SQL to implement a filter or a look-up. Apparently. To be honest I can't ever remember a case where I had to do this and it worked (although I've had a few cases where turning a pipelined function into a subquery or inline view improved performance). Maybe I've led a sheltered life. Certainly, I would welcome benchmarked citations for counter-examples.

Comment: Sometimes select sub-queries are faster then joins though.  Simply needs testing.

Comment: @OlafurTryggvason - A subquery is still SQL.

Answer (score 2):

There would be a very small number of circumstances in which the function method would be optimal, and by default I would not use it. Joins are what databases are designed to do, so they should be your first choice.

Answer (score 1):

What did you find out yourself using those 2 different queries?

In my experience, a join is 9 out of 10 times faster than a function. At least when you are accessing another query / table / view in the function. The function needs to be evaluated each run, the join probably generates a bigger dataset, but can perform better because it only has to join the tables (on keys) which is pretty fast.

Comment: The first query (with the function) was found in a existing application I am working on. The second query is more like I do generaly, so before rewriting all the queries with joins, I try to know witch one is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

OR forget about the outer join and put the select statement that does the translation in the select list [this is sometimes faster that outer join]:

```
SELECT field1, field2
, (select libelle from t_statut_ope b where b.id_statut = a.field2) libelle
FROM table1 a
WHERE 1=1
;
```

Comment: Interresting, do you khow when / why it is sometime faster ?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen "select statement in select list" to be slower than "outer-join".  I suspect that the extra work required for Oracle to "create" the  missing records causes the slowdown for outer-join.  This work increases for very large tables on either side.